# Check type of sub-element of JSON-object in Couchbase View

Tags: couchbase

Document have sub-element with name 'date'. The date can be in two formats:

1) Millisecond.

```
"date" : "31287356871253"
```

2) Map-format :

```
"date": {
  "year": "...",
  "month": "...",
  ...
}
```

Is there a possibility for detect 'type' of sub-element in Couchbase View? The suitable solution in the documentation I don't  find.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about map/reduce index views. If so, it would probably just be a simple matter of JavaScript. Something like:

```
if(doc.date.year) {
    // it's the 2nd format
} else {
    // it's the 1st format
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. It works, but I wanted to find a more elegant solution, so as not to be tied to the presence of a specific field, but a method that checks the type of the element.

Comment: JSON doesn't have a "type" in the same way that, say, a C# or Java object does. You might be able to try something like `typeof doc.date`, that might be another option. But I don't think that's going to differentiate between `{"year": "...", "month": "..."}` and `{"yr": "...", "mnth": "..."}`, for instance.